# Configure OpenCV with Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers on Windows7

Tags: opencv, windows-7, eclipse-cdt

I am using, Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Juno) and open cv. I tried to follow the documentation over internet. Most of them is around linux machine. My OS is Windows7. Please guide me to configure open cv.

Regards,
Priyank

Comment: One who has marked this question down, can you please explain why? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: you should be more specific about what your problem. Try to add something about what you have done and what results you've got.

Comment: I am confused. Where to start? Can't it be the situation, or I have to fail according to the geek's expactations? Why would i even configure it to the linux way if I am not getting the windows way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to:

1. Install eclipse
2. Install cdt plugin for eclipse
3. Install mingw
4. Build and install opencv
5. Setup project

Google search phrase is obvious: **eclipse windows opencv**

Comment: MinGW is under GPL license. Do I have any other alternatives to MinGW which can fall under LGPL or MIT kind of license?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the timely and accurate response. :)

Comment: and yes I tried the search phrase earlier but most of them were leading to JavaCV options